# Monitor a machine plugged on a mirroring interface

Tags: monitoring, mirroring, snort

I've read that if I configure port span, I can no longer use that interface to pass normal trafic.
However, I'd like to monitor the machine plugged to that interface, with nagios..

Does anyone know a workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put a second NIC in that machine and plug it into a normal port and monitor it over that interface.